# What is recommended solution for monitoring heterogeneous infrastructure?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I am looking for monitoring tool for the following use cases:

- Collect basic metrics about virtual machine (cpu usage, memory usage, i/o, available space)
- Extract metrics from SQL Server (probably running some queries)
- Extract information from external service about processing i.e how many processing are currently running and for how long. I am thinking about writing python scripts, but don't know how to combine with monitoring tool
- Have the ability to plot charts and manage alerts and it will nice to have ability to send not only mails, but send message to slack/ms teams.

I was thing about Prometheus, because it has wmi_exporter, node_exporter, sql exporter, alert manager with possibility to send notifications to multiple destinations, but I don't know what to do with this external service and python scripts.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus can definitely do what you say you need done. Some of it may not be trivial, but you can definitely fill in the blanks yourself.

E.g. you can get machine metrics basically out of the box by firing up a node_exporter and having it scraped by Prometheus, but I don't think it has e.g. information on all running processes. The latter might require you to write an agent/exporter: a simple web server that exposes metrics on `/metrics`; there exists a [Python client library](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) to help with that. Or have said processes (assuming they're your code) push metrics to a [Pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) instead, if they're short lived batch jobs.

Oh, and for charts/dashboards you probably want [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), as Prometheus' abilities in that area are rather limited and Grafana integrates rather well with Prometheus.